# Angular client side validation special case

Tags: angularjs

```
<input id="declarationAcknowledgement" name="declarationAcknowledgement" ng-false-value="false" ng-model="formData.declarationAcknowledgement" ng-true-value="true" type="checkbox" />

<label data-localize="I Agree" for="declarationAcknowledgement" >I Agree</label>

<div class="pw-form-inline-error" data-localize="Accept to proceed" ng-show="(peopleworksForm.declarationAcknowledgement.$dirty || peopleworksForm.submited)  && formData.declarationAcknowledgement != 'true'">Accept to proceed</div>
```

this is my view side inside my controller I set  "Form.submited = true"

what I want is if the user check the check box if value is not equals to 'true' set the form.$valid false from view side not in controller how can I do this. Can any one help me?

Answer (score 1):

try this.. add `required="required"` and make `ng-false-value=""`

```
  <input required="required" name="declarationAcknowledgement" ng-false-value="" ng-model="formData.declarationAcknowledgement" ng-true-value="true" type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: but the thing is when I get data from db and set to scope if it is false check box should not be checked. you may understand me

Comment: i really do not think, that checkbox is checked, when value is false.. it wont be.. thats an inbuilt functionality...

Comment: no you messed up. What I really want to do is I have a record in db.when formData.declarationAcknowledgement = 'false' the check box should not be checked. and when formData.declarationAcknowledgement = 'true' check box should be checked. before load the page I fill $scope inside controller with either true or false. also I want to record value false in db when user didn't checked check box. as you say if "ng-false-value=""" it will not save value as false in scope variable

Comment: question/comments does not seem to be in sync.. as per question form should be invalid if value is false, but then you want to save false in db?? confused...